# request.getSession() creating new session after sendRedirect()

Tags: jsp, session, jakarta-ee, servlets, struts2

We are developing travel application. Through this flight, Hotel, Bus tickets will be booked. It is product based application. Nearly we have 25 clients(3 clients are using, for remaining still developing). We are maintaining one server for all clients. One server(application) multiple clients is the great achievement in my application. But the problem is every client is having different payment gateways for their money transfer like EBS, HDFC, ICICI, ATOM etc.  We have to use sendRedriect() to call their payment gateway system.

```
response.sendRedirect("hdfc link....");
```

before redirecting we are storing nearly 7-9 objects in session scope, and each object will contain nearly 35-50 variables. 
After completion of the payment gateway process that will be redirected to my application. When i try to get the session

```
request.getSession();
```

it is creating new session for some times(5 out of 10 times).

The variables which are stored in request scope are crucial for me. and i cant store it into database because they are very huge. For every request we are generating random number whose length is 25. With that random number the session variables are stored.

```
session.setAttribute("flightStatus"+randomNumber, flightstatus object);
```

So please suggest how to get back the previous session, and why the previous session is invalidated and new session is getting create.

Comment: without further information its very hard to help.what are those use-case where session is created as new?? is there any session timeout etc?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi There is no time out for session.

Comment: are you explicity doing any url-rewriting or storing the session anywhere in cookie? And also in what scenario is the session created newly?

Comment: unable to trace the scenario...

Comment: You can store it in the session/request but it's too big to store in a database? That doesn't make any sense. That aside, if you're on the same server, the session isn't timing out, you're sharing sessions between HTTP and HTTPS, it's going to be very difficult for anyone but you to figure out why the session is being dropped--it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use request.getSession(false) . If you don't want to get new session.

Read this doc: [request.getSession(false)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29)